# Open chm file in java

Tags: java, chm

I want to open a CHM (help) file from my java application...
My code looks like this:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hh.exe myhelpfile.chm");`

It works, but how can I open it with a specific page??

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

> **Is it possible to open a specific topic from the Hh.exe command line?**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms669980(VS.85).aspx#is_it_possible_to_open_a_specific_topic_from_the_hh.exe_command_line_

Comment: This seems to apply when using the hh execute instruction, nevertheless if you want to use the Desktop class included in Java6, it might not apply :(

Answer (score 0):

```
String s;
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmsee sample.chm");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("exit: " + p.exitValue());
        p.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```