# how to open help file in java

Tags: java, chm

i want to open .chm help file when click on Help button on swing window. how should i do?

```
if(e.getActionCommand() == "Help" ){
        Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try
        {
        Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("F:\OfficeCommunicatorClient\src\resources\User Account HelpNew.chm\");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: try this 
http://forums.sureshkumar.net/java-technologies/9438-opening-help-chm-files-java.html

Comment: probably not an error here, but Strings should be compared using `equals` not `==`. And much better IMO is to use a constant for the ActionCommand (`CMD_HELP = "Help"`).

Comment: 1) `src\resources\User Account HelpNew.chm` The combination of `src` & `resources` makes me think this is an application resource that will arrive at the computer of the end user in a Jar.  If so, it cannot be accessed by `File` at that point, only `URL`. 2) Using `exec` is obviously platform dependent, what do you intend to do for users of *nix & OS X? 3) There are a number of things wrong with that invocation of `exec`, but I do not think it is a viable approach in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
from this site [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/102571/Open-a-chm-file-in-java-help-please)

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hh.exe F:/OfficeCommunicatorClient/src/resources/User Account HelpNew.chm");
```

check this also [open  chm file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509437/open-chm-file-in-java)

Comment: how can i get it working in executable jar file. because when i create it there may be vary file path. i dont want absolute path here.

Comment: @Vinay : for that please try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from

Comment: when i tried for this  private String path = ClientLoginUI.class.getResource("/resources/UserAccountHelpNew.chm").getPath();        i got error message that "file could not open"

Comment: try this for the path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218061/get-the-applications-path

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9073/discussion-between-vinay-and-presleydias)

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove last '\'. It suggests it is a directory instead of a file.

Secondly you should use either double '\' or single '/':
F:\\OfficeCommunicatorClient\\src\\resources\\User Account HelpNew.chm
or
F:/OfficeCommunicatorClient/src/resources/User Account HelpNew.chm

@edit
It seems that the help cannot be run itself. Use hh.exe to open the help file. Moreover the file must be inside "", so the string should look like:
"hh.exe \"F:/OfficeCommunicatorClient/src/resources/User Account HelpNew.chm\""

To get the path you are relative to, use this sample code:

```
File f = new File(".");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: ya i have done that but its still not opening. its shoeing following error:      Cannot run program ""F:\OfficeCommunicatorClient\src\resources\User": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: remove the spaces in the name of your .chm file.

Comment: how can i get it working in executable jar file. because when i create it there may be vary file path. i dont want absolute path here..